# AWS lambda serverless, when re-deploying api-gateway subdomain changes

Tags: aws-api-gateway, aws-serverless

Sometimes when I deploy my serverless lambda using `serverless --stage=production deploy` my API Gateway subdomain changes, I cannot figure out why it changes, and it's a bit annoying to update all clients to point to new url.

before: `https://o2676lowsf.my-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/production`, after: `https://88vdel0d4j.my-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/production`

Comment: can you please share a little bit more about the serverless config?

Answer (score 0):

If your subdomain changes, this would indicate that the deployment is a fresh one and not an update. For example, if you run `sls remove`, a subsequent `sls deploy` would naturally create a new one. Also if your service name, stage or region changes, you get a new one.

I would check that nothing in your deployment/CI process removes the old one prior to deploying the new one. If it's simply an update to an existing API (same service name and stage in the same region), the subdomain does not change.

Comment: one thing I noticed is that i had hidden `.serverless` directory in gitignore, so does it mean that next developer would do have done deployment like it's a fresh one?

Comment: No. Serverless creates a persistent CloudFormation stack in your AWS account based on your service name and stage. All subsequent deployments modify this stack instead of creating a new one (along with a new API) if it exists.